# CMake - OpenVR compilation issues

Tags: c++, build, cmake, openvr

I am currently re-working my game/rendering engine. I am doing it cross-platform so have switched to using a CMake build process. I have had no issues building GLFW or GLAD but ran into problems with openvr

It's a fairly basic build right now but I'm relatively new to it

```
add_subdirectory(lib/openvr)
add_subdirectory(lib/glfw)
add_subdirectory(lib/glad)

target_link_libraries(flux glad glfw openvr_api64)
```

This all worked fine, can include the headers etc but I get a lot of unresolved external errors

> __imp_VR_GetGenericInterface
>   __imp_VR_IsInterfaceVersionValid
>   __imp_VR_InitInternal2

and so on...

I've looked at the CMakeLists file in the repo but couldn't find anything that I know of
https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr

Any input would be nice

Comment: Probably, these unresolved symbols are defined in `openvr_api64` library, but I don't see linking with that library in your code.

Comment: The ... in the target_link_libraries call has openvr_api64, I should of been more specific with that one

Comment: Ok, now it is time to provide more detailed description about your problem: including the **exact error message** into the question. That message should contain, among other things, the name of the linked file. (Ideally, we want to find [mcve] in your question post).

Answer (score 0):

The current master branch of [ValveSoftware/openvr](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr) has a broken build, it has missing files and wrong include paths

#### TL;DR

ValveSoftware/openvr has a broken build, use my fork with a fixed build:
https://github.com/okawo80085/openvr

#### Long Version

It has been broken on the last release or two(idr)

I ran into this issue myself when I got around to making openvr a proper dep for my driver, and the easiest way to work around this issue (cuz Valve did not fix it for more then 6 months now, even though there are PRs fixing it for them and issues raised regarding broken builds) is to fork openvr and fix it yourself, which is what I also ended up doing

[here is my fork](https://github.com/okawo80085/openvr) - it has a working build and a relatively recently built libs for Linux in `openvr/libs/{platform}{architecture}`, if you're gonna add it as a subdirectory use the repository root